# how can i change streaming url and ,imageurl and Radio name on same page using onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="http://s2.whsh4u.com/mrp.js" >< /script  >
< center >
    < img src="http://malayalamonlineradio.in/wp/radio-red947.jpg" />< br/>
    Now playing: < b>Radio Titile< /b>
< /center>
< script type="text/javascript" >
    MRP.insert({'url':'http://109.169.59.107:8038/;.mp3','codec':'mp3','volume':65,'autoplay':true,'buffering':7,'title':'Radio Red F M','welcome':'Connecting','bgcolor':'#FFFFFF','skin':'faredirfare','width':269,'height':52});
< /script >
```

Comment: By wrapping it in a function with arguments and calling that function with on onclick handler on a button element.

Comment: Please edit your question to deliver additional information (click the "edit" link below the post).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
  
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    changer(this);
    
    });
}
  
  function changer(radio){
    alert('Radio Station '+radio.dataset.station+'\n\nStation image '+radio.dataset.img+'\n\n Radio station name '+radio.dataset.name);
    
    }
```

```html
<button data-station="http://radio1" data-img="http://radio1blah-balh" data-name="radio 1">Radio 1</button>
<button data-station="http://radio2" data-img="http://radio2blah-balh" data-name="radio 2">Radio 2</button>
<button data-station="http://radio2" data-img="http://radio3blah-balh" data-3ame="radio 1">Radio 3</button>
```